# How install Ubuntu on Dell 3521 Laptop with new blank disk

Tags: system-installation, dell, laptop

I am fixing a Dell 3521 laptop for a friend.

The old hard drive was broken. Put in a Western Digital-blue 320 GB disk.

Using a freeware bootable CD formatted the hard drive and it found zero bad blocks.  It currently has Fat32.  Want to use whatever Ubuntu likes best.

There will be no other OS.  Just Ubuntu on a Dell 3521 Laptop.

1. What version of Ubuntu should I use?
2. Then make how a bootable Ubuntu install CD.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As for #1 of your question, I just looked at the specs online and you should be able to use the latest version of Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) with ease.

For #2 of you questions I want to simply point you to the right direction for more information. This you will find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD).

As far of the format for the HDD, leave it blank, the installer will handle that for you, just make sure to disable fast boot and secure boot as its known to cause troubles along the way.